# Add recipients to existing recipient list with C# code - Sitecore Email campaign manager

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-ecm

I want to add new recipients to existing recipientlist using code. I tried with below code but it didnt work.

```cs
TargetAudience recipientList = Factory.GetTargetAudience("RecipientListId");
if ((recipientList != null))
{
       Contact contact = //I dont know how to create object for this, because it is protected class
       contact.Profile.Email = "my Email";
       contact.Profile.Name = "My Name";
       contact.Profile.FullName = "Full Name";
       recipientList.Subscribers.Add(contact);
 }
```

Please help me to acheive this,

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a contact from the username of the user.
This method gets the contact by  email address and contains code to get the username from the email address.

```cs
 public Contact GetContact(string email)
 {
        // managerRoot is the top level ECM item
        ManagerRoot managerRootFromId = Factory.GetManagerRootFromID(managerRoot.ID.ToString());
        var username = Util.AddressToUserName(email);
        string commonDomain = managerRootFromId.Settings.CommonDomain;
        string fullName = commonDomain + "\\" + Util.AddressToUserName(username);

        if (User.Exists(fullName))
        {
            return Contact.FromName(fullName);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

You should then be able to add the Contact to the subscription list.

Or once you have the Contact you can set the profile values and use the subscribe method.

```cs
contact.InnerUser.Profile["Fullname"] = string.Format("{0} {1}",person.Firstname,person.Surname);
contact.Subscribe(subscriptionLists);
```

You can also add ECM users by using the following code supplying the email address as the localname.

```cs
 protected static Contact CreateAnonymousECMUser(string localName, ManagerRoot root)
 {
        Contact contact = (Contact)null;
        if (root != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(localName))
        {
            string commonDomain = root.Settings.CommonDomain;
            Assert.IsNotNullOrEmpty(commonDomain, EcmTexts.Localize("The Common Domain setting is not set.", new object[0]));
            string str = commonDomain + "\\" + Util.AddressToUserName(localName);
            while (User.Exists(str))
                str = str + "_";
            string password = new PasswordGenerator()
            {
                MinimumCharacters = 14
            }.Generate();
            System.Web.Security.Membership.CreateUser(str, password, localName);
            contact = Contact.FromName(str);
            contact.Profile.ProfileItemId = root.Settings.SubscriberProfile;
            contact.Profile.Save();
        }
        return contact;
  }
```

Comment: Do I want to add an user before adding them to RecipientList. Can you help me how to add user

Comment: Code added to add user

Comment: There is code in WFFM to create users and assign them to a receipient list - it might be more flexible to use this.

Comment: WFFM means??. Sorry I am new to sitecore

Comment: Web forms for Marketers - it's another Sitecore module.

Comment: If possible can you share me the link to that thread. Really appreciate your help :)

Comment: https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/products/web_forms2/24/web%20forms%20for%20marketers%20v2_4%20user%20guide-a4.pdf read the bit about ECM integration